# How to use subdomain to delegate client id for authentication into Azure B2C

Tags: .net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to stand up a dot net core 2.2 web app that will use the subdomain to determine what client id I should use to authenticate the user in Azure B2C.  I have an API that I'm calling that will provide the client id for the subdomain.

Is it possible to swap out client ids at run time or does that have to be configured at start-up?

*Startup.cs*

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
{
    sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})
.AddAzureAdB2C(options => Configuration.Bind("Authentication:AzureAdB2C", options))
.AddCookie();
```

*`OnRedirectToIdentityProvider` Event*

```
public async Task OnRedirectToIdentityProvider(RedirectContext context)
{
    var defaultClientId = AzureAdB2COptions.ClientId;

    var fullAddress = context.HttpContext?.Request?.Headers?["Host"].ToString()?.Split(':');
    var subdomain = fullAddress[0];
    var tenant = await _api.GetConfig(subdomain);

    if (tenant != null &&
        !tenant.ClientId.Equals(defaultClientId))
    {
       context.Options.ClientId = tenant.ClientId;
    }

    var defaultPolicy = AzureAdB2COptions.DefaultPolicy;
    if (context.Properties.Items.TryGetValue(AzureAdB2COptions.PolicyAuthenticationProperty,
            out var policy) &&
        !policy.Equals(defaultPolicy))
    {
        context.ProtocolMessage.Scope = AzureAdB2COptions.ApiScopes;
        context.ProtocolMessage.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken;
        context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress = context.ProtocolMessage.IssuerAddress
            .ToLower().Replace(defaultPolicy.ToLower(), policy.ToLower());
        context.Properties.Items.Remove(AzureAdB2COptions.PolicyAuthenticationProperty);
    }
    else
    {
        context.ProtocolMessage.Scope = AzureAdB2COptions.ApiScopes;
    }

    return;
}
```

When the app loads, the initial configuration works:  `client1.domain.com` is mapped to the client id configured at start up and logins work correctly.  If I change the subdomain I swap out the client id in the `OnRedirectToIdentityProvider` event, but am returned a `IDX10214: Audience validation failed error`.

Answer (score 1):

Well that sucked, but I had to specify valid audiences on the token validation params in my open-id config.

```
public void Configure(string name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
{
    options.ClientId = AzureAdB2COptions.ClientId;
    options.Authority = AzureAdB2COptions.Authority;
    options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
    {
        NameClaimType = "name",
        ValidAudiences = new[] { "clientid1", "clientid2", "etca" }
    };

    options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
    {
        OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider,
        OnRemoteFailure = OnRemoteFailure,
        OnAuthorizationCodeReceived = OnAuthorizationCodeReceived
    };
}
```

Comment: Hey Mike, if your answer solved the question, please go ahead and [mark it as the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkiIZ.png). Thanks!